# How can I force stop my crawler on getting a specific url crawled last time?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler, html-parsing

I am making a crawler to find out recently added youtube videos I want to stop my crawler when it reaches old video(crawled in previous turn). I am not using scrapy and beautifulsoup I am using python libraries. Please suggest me any option

Answer (score 0):

won't simple check and pass work?

```
if video in list_of_crawled_videos:
    pass
else:
    list_of_crawled_videos.append(video)
```

Comment: No it just not take that particular video but remain continue

Comment: then replace `break` on `pass` =)

Comment: @Amrinder, was my suggestion helpful?